# Как протестировать сервис посылающий некие данные по http?

Tags: c#, http, веб-сервер, testng

Есть ли какой-нибудь простенький веб сервер, который бы принимал бы все что в него шлют и выводил на консоль?

Comment: mitmproxy делает все то же самое, но еще и встает между клиентом и сервером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это сервис, то зачем ему сервер?
Все равно, что к автомобилю цеплять локомотив, а не прицеп с грузом.

А так, есть сниффер Fiddler, действует по принципу MITM, все HTTP/HTTPS логирует. **Ставится на клиенте**.

Comment: Возможно не до конца описал, там один сервис шлет пакеты другому.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете в свой солюшн добавить новый проект, консольное приложение, которое подымет веб-сервер и будет логировать запросы в консоль.

В конфигурации для Debug будете подключаться к этому фейковому сайту, видеть свои запросы.

Также если вы упомянули слово тестирование - вы можете в своём сервисе вместо реального клиента (у вас же там интерфейс, да?) подставлять mock-клиента. Путь ведущий к написанию юнит-тестов: в отличие от разового "протестировал и забыли": через пятьдесят коммитов нужно проверять заново руками, а до тех пор не быть уверенным точно, работает или нет.

Вариант с прокси - это для разовой ручной проверки. Fiddler - хорошая рекомендация, присоединяюсь.

И я конечно понимаю, что вам очень хочется здесь и сейчас поставить прокси, посмотреть запросы и забыть... Но если есть возможность вложиться в тесты - то используйте эту возможность - это хорошие инвестиции в будущее.

Comment: Да можно конечно самому наколеночный сделать, но я хотел бы в арсенале иметь инструмент для мнгновенной проверки. Юнит тесты все ок проходят я теперь хочу посмотреть как оно в пакете приходит.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Тогда ставьте галку на варианте с фиддлером - самое то.

Comment: @A K не он платный )